# Python Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I simply want to add data frames that are stored in a dictionary.  intuitively I would want to loop the dictionary.  However  I do not have an initial dataframe with zero values.  What is the best way to accomplish that elegantly.  Currently I am doing the following:

```
dict = {'B' :df1, 'C':df2, 'D': df3}

total = dict['B'] + dict['C'] + dict['D']
```

the dfs are initialized from reading from a csv file and there could be more than 3.

How can I accomplish this in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the dict values to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat), example:

```
In [195]:
d = {}
d['a'] = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5)})
d['b'] = pd.DataFrame({'b':np.arange(5)})
total = pd.concat(d.values(), axis=1)
total.sum()

Out[195]:
a    10
b    10
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add (and not concatenate as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141382/3991125)) these DataFrames you could use something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))

d = {'a': df1, 'b': df2, 'c': df3, 'd': df4}
total = 0    

for key, df in d.items():
    total += df
```

Comment: here is the error i get:---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1843cd9e7fa8> in <module>()
     10 
     11 for key, df in d.items():
---> 12     total += df

NameError: name 'total' is not defined

Comment: @AlMerchant: You're right. I forgot to initialize the variable `total` and edited my answer accordingly. Sorry for that.

Comment: i guess the problem boils down to how do i know whether a variable is undefined in python?

Comment: As you described - you get a `NameError` telling you that a variable (in this case `total` is not defined). Did I solve your main problem concerning the addition of dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a panel and then sum:

```
pd.Panel(dict).sum()
```

On a side note, it's not best practice to overwrite the inbuilt `dict` function

Answer (score 0):

just for completeness,  here is what demonstrates the problem and the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2))

d = {'a': df1, 'b': df2, 'c': df3, 'd': df4}

for key, df in d.items():
    if 'total' in locals():
        print("found")
        total += df
    else:
        print("not")
        total = df

print(total)
del total
```